# Bootstrap Tooltips - not working at all

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I'm trying to implement bootstrap tooltips on my site - you'd think it would be easy enough, but something is not working correctly - the bootstrap tooltip is not functioning.

I'm calling all the right scripts, stylesheets and javascript - I believe. I'm following the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/TSZSL/171/ and I believe this javascript could be throwing me?

```
$('.example').tooltip();
```

[Here's](http://macgeniushosting.com/hosting/prestashop-hosting/) the page I'm referring to. I just get a regular tooltip with no bootstrap functionality.

Comment: I've had a similar problem with bootstrap tooltip on hover, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737650/bootstrap-tooltip-css-changes-work-in-file-but-not-with-jquery)

Comment: Look at your browser console and you'll see. GitHub isn't a CDN

Comment: Please add at the parts of your code not working. The link to your site you provided will no longer demonstrate the issue once you have solved the problem. Also please don't expect from us to search the whole code of your site for possible problems.

Comment: 171 saves on jsfiddle... that's a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your reference to boostrap's tooltip library. You can't link to it like that; it's not a CDN...

`<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>`.

Use netdna's complete JS package or host the individual script yourself. See [BootstrapCDN](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/).

`<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: You're the best - thanks a ton - I don't know how that got in there, but I totally missed it!